# Does Nvidia GPU work with AMD APU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, compatibility

Recently, I built a cheap PC with AMD A4-6300 and so far I had lots of trouble installing the propriety driver in Ubuntu 16.04 (I know it the propriety driver supports 14.04 but I can't let go of 16.04 for some reason :D ). Now, I am planning to buy a cheap Nvidia GT 730 or 210.

My question is, will it work with my current CPU? If yes, how well will it work? Do I need to do some voodoo magic to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I'm also planning to buy another monitor. Should I connect the first monitor on the APU and the other one on the GPU? Or should I just use a VGA splitter and connect it on the GPU?

Comment: Also, there is the opensource Radeon Driver. https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/. This is AMD developed, and so has support from them with their devs working on it.

Comment: I am using it right now but my display is kind of messed up. It show this weird white color dragged to right whenever there is a white element(colors, text, menus) over a dark background. Also it failed to recognize my display's maximum resolution, so I needed to do some stuff to make it work. I tried testing other monitors, but still no luck. I'll try using different VGA cables later to test it. I don't know if these problems are caused by the GPU drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should. Your GPU and CPU are different. So, Ubuntu would work. Just make sure you disable the AMD in the UEFI, before this. This is because it *may* happen that Ubuntu would get confused and select the wrong GPU.

Comment: I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 Unity with the GT 730 plugged in. It didn't auto install the opensource drivers, so I installed the Nvidia 375 driver and it is now working smoothly. I'm even playing Skyrim on Wine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have always been using AMD CPU + NVIDIA GPU configuration, so I can tell you my experience:

Will it work?

Well, it's impossible to know. I had a GT440 and it wasn't supported by Ubuntu Operating Systems. But I'm running Ubuntu right now with a GTX750.

People say AMD GPUs work better with Linux than Nvidia. But I can tell you that Nvidia CAN work fine.